# Parallel Random Forests with doSMP and foreach drastically increase memory usage (on Windows)

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, random-forest

When executing random forest in serial it uses 8GB of RAM on my system, when doing it in parallel it uses more than twice te RAM (18GB). How can I keep it to 8GB when doing it in parallel? Here's the code:

```
install.packages('foreach')
install.packages('doSMP')
install.packages('randomForest')

library('foreach')
library('doSMP')
library('randomForest')

NbrOfCores <- 8 
workers <- startWorkers(NbrOfCores) # number of cores
registerDoSMP(workers)
getDoParName() # check name of parallel backend
getDoParVersion() # check version of parallel backend
getDoParWorkers() # check number of workers


#creating data and setting options for random forests
#if your run this please adapt it so it won't crash your system! This amount of data  uses up to 18GB of RAM.
x <- matrix(runif(500000), 100000)
y <- gl(2, 50000)
#options
set.seed(1)
ntree=1000
ntree2 <- ntree/NbrOfCores


gc()

#running serialized version of random forests

system.time(
rf1 <- randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree))


gc()


#running parallel version of random forests

system.time(
rf2 <- foreach(ntree = rep(ntree2, 8), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree))
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, SMP will duplicate the input so that each process will get its own copy. This could be escaped by using `multicore`, yet there is also another problem -- each invocation of `randomForest` will also make an internal copy of the input.

The best you can do it to cut some usage by making `randomForest` drop the forest model itself (with `keep.forest=FALSE`) and doing testing along with training (by using `xtest` and possibly `ytest` arguments).

Comment: Good suggestion but I need the forest model to be able to make predictions in the future (i.e., I need to build the model now, and score new data later). Regarding the multicore package: it is only for Unix (and I'm on Windows, cf. my question).

Answer (score 1):

Random forest objects can get very large with moderate sized data sets, so the increase may be related to storing the model object.

To test this, you should really have two different sessions.

Try running another model in parallel that does not have a large footprint (lda for example) and see if you get the same increase in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens is the following. As your parent process spawns child processes, the memory is shared, i.e. no significant increase in ram usage occurs. However, as the child processes start building the random forests, they create many new intermediate objects, which are not in shared memory and are potentially fairly large.

So my answer is that there is, disappointingly, probably no easy way around it, at least using the randomForest package -- though I would be very interested if someone was aware of one.